# How do I avoid writing DataContract(IsReference=true)

Tags: entity-framework, wcf

I have a Code First model in Entity Framework 6. However, there are circular references so I have to add DataContract attributes to all those entities and DataMember attributes too, in order to get the entities serialized correclty by WCF.

I would like to avoid to clutter the entities with these attributes, and as  far as I can see, this would be possible if I could change the default value of the IsReference parameter to true.

Does anyone know how to do this, or is there any other (simple) way?

Comment: Why don't you create flattened data contracts, to avoid these issues?

Comment: You could probably use something like AutoMapper to create DTOs which you could then decorate for serialization. This way your original entities remain as is.

Comment: In this case I want to stick with my POCO:s in my domain model and not use any DTO:s.

Comment: In this case I want to stick with my POCO:s in my domain model and not use any DTO:s. In .net 3.5 the data contract attributes was no longer required since it felt annoying to have to write attribute for all classes and properties. However if you have circular references, which is quite common in EF (back references), then you're on your own and get all the fun of writing all the attributes....